# Does the gradient theorem holds for a continuous function with weak derivatives on a convex set?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, differential-calculus

Let $\Omega$ be a convex open set in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space whose closure is compact.

Let $f$ be a real-valued continuous function on $\overline{\Omega}$ which also belongs to the Sobolev space $H^1(\overline{\Omega})$.

Then, I wonder if the (extended version of) the gradient theorem regarding the line integral holds for this $f$. That is, for any pair of points $a,b \in \overline{\Omega}$ and some $C^1$ curve $\gamma : [0,1] \to \overline{\Omega}$ with $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma(1)=b$, do we have
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \nabla f (\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t)dt= f(b)-f(a)
\end{equation}

I guess that we need to be careful about the choice of $\gamma$ to make sense of the integral on the left, but I am not sure..Could anyone please help me?

Comment: You would need to exclude some curves, as for the Lipschitz function $f(x,y)=|x-y|$ the integrand would not make sense for the curve $\gamma(t)=(t,t)$. Check out this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/908184/484640 and the references therein